# store selected cells textLabel text in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

How do i store all selected cells text label text in a NSMutableArray?
How do i remove the correct cells text from the NSMutableArray when a cell is deselected?

What i have this far:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

 if ([self.allSelectedUsers containsObject:indexPath]) {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
     NSLog(@"Yeeees");
 }else{
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
 }

 // Configure the cell
 cell.textLabel.text = object[@"username"];
 return cell;
}
```

This is when i'm selecting a cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
if ([self.allSelectedUsers containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [self.allSelectedUsers removeObject:indexPath];
}
else{
    [self.allSelectedUsers addObject:indexPath];
}
NSLog(@"%d", self.allSelectedUsers);
[tableView reloadData];

}
```

When i check the log it doesn't display anything about the cells text label.

Comment: have you alloc init `self.allSelectedUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can't see how you're getting `object` instance, I suggest you to get back cell and read the title again.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath        
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // Lazy initialise array
    if (!self.allSelectedUsers) {
        self.allSelectedUsers = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

    // Take action
    if ([self.allSelectedUsers containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.allSelectedUsers removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self.allSelectedUsers addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];

    // Logging all selected users
    for (NSIndexPath *sIndexPath in self.allSelectedUsers) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sIndexPath].textLabel.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently storing `NSIndexPath` objects, not `NSString` objects, so it's not exactly what your question is asking. With your `PFTableViewController`, you have access to the selector `objectAtIndexPath:`.

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.allSelectedUsers) {
  NSLog(@"%@", [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath][@"username"]);
}
```

**Note:** You shouldn't be calling `reloadData` in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` responder; change the accessory type for the cell instead.

```
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
```

You should also implement `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` to know when a user deselects a row.

Comment: So i should add the for-loop in objectAtIndexPath? and then replace the [tableView reloadData] with the setAccessoryType?

Comment: That `for` loop can be used anywhere within your `PFTableViewController`.